# Algebraic mean problem

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

The Question is:

$27pqr \geq (p+q+r)^3$ and $3p+4q+5r=12$, then what is the greatest value of $p^3+q^4+r^5$?

How do i solve this problem? Im think harmonic mean has to be used along with geometric mean but i havent been able to equate them to find the answer. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply $AM\geqslant GM$ on $p,q,r$. You are given that converse is true. Hence, $AM=GM$ and $p=q=r$

[image]

Take any 3 points on curve of $\ln(x)$

Note that the centroid($\frac{p+q+r}3,\frac{\ln p +\ln q+\ln r}3$) of these points will always be below this curve. Hence, y-coordinate of centroid will be less than that of curve when you draw a line parallel to y-axis at the point. The line will be $x=\frac{p+q+r}3$. Hence,

$$\frac{\ln p +\ln q+\ln r}3\leqslant \ln{\frac{p+q+r}3}$$

$${(pqr)}^{1/3}\leqslant p+q+r$$
Clearly, inequality will be achieved only when you take all 3 points the same.

Comment: Wow I never thought about it that way!

Comment: But I didnt get p=q=r ,how can you be certain of that?

Comment: @user129048 Equality is achieved only when all are equal. Apply Jensen's inequality on $\ln(x)$ and it will be clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i got it! You're awesome! (lol)

Comment: @user129048 You should accept this answer by clicking on green tick next to my answer

Comment: Oh yes ofcourse